# Invalid CSS ::last-child in all.css

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Writing a CSS parser in Nim, I'm testing it on Stack Overflow's `all.css` file and found the following invalid selector.

```
.badge1-alternate::last-child,.badge2-alternate::last-child,.badge3-alternate::last-child,.badge-how-to::last-child {
    margin-right: 0
}
```

Each `::last-child` should be `:last-child`. Right now the entire rule will be ignored, so perhaps it's not needed and can be removed entirely. Just thought I'd throw it out there.

I guess this should be phrased as a question... so is this a bug or does Stack Overflow intend for this selector to be written as is? :-)

Comment: The setup for this question is hilarious.

Comment: I'd guess it was just a thinko of someone updating pseudo-elements to the more modern `::` form accidentally doing it with this pesudo-class too.

Comment: @JonHanna: Most likely that's the case. @ BoltClock: Always nice to see the tools we write do the job they're supposed to. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for taking the time to point this out. This has been updated.